# Ubuntu 16.04 not working with video messed up?

Tags: 16.04

About 3 days ago I tried the nightly build and it was working... today with the final release, the video is always messed up (showing with a ratio of about `2.35 : 1` and then the video is all messed up.  Is there something wrong or waiting for a fix?

**P.S.** I even upgraded VirtualBox to the latest version (from a version that I installed 2, 3 months ago) and it is the same. After some trial and error, it seemed like when I set the Number of Processors to more than 1, then this issue will happen sometimes. The Number of Processors has to be set to 1 for this issue not to occur.

Other versions of Ubuntu didn't have this issue, and, the computer I am using is an iMac 27 inch Retina as of late 2015.

**P.P.S.** this issue does not happen on a Macbook Pro at all (made as of late 2013).